# $Ran(A-\lambda)^{\perp} = Ker(A-\lambda)$ for self-adjoint operator $A$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

[image: Thereom 5.5]I am reading through Theorem 5.5 in Hislop and Sigal, and I have the following confusion about the proof for item 2.
My confusion is, why can you immediately conclude that
\begin{equation}\label{key}
 Ran(A-\lambda)^{\perp} = Ker(A^{*}-\lambda)?
\end{equation}
Surely, wouldn't it be
\begin{equation}
 Ran(A-\lambda)^{\perp} = Ker(A^{*}-\overline{\lambda})?
\end{equation}
where $ \overline{\lambda} $ denotes the complex conjugate of $ \lambda $.

The result in Chapter $ 4 $ they refer to I believe is the standard result of $ \mathcal{H} $ being split into the orthogonal sum $ \overline{Ran A} \oplus Ker(A^{*}) $, and possibly the result that
\begin{equation}
 \sigma(A^{*}) = \overline{\sigma(A)},
\end{equation}
if $ A $ is closed.
Maybe the result
\begin{equation}
 Ran(A-\lambda)^{\perp} = Ker(A^{*}-\lambda)
\end{equation}
follows from
\begin{equation}
 \sigma(A^{*}) = \overline{\sigma(A)}?
\end{equation}

Thank you!

Edit: Sorry, I should have clarified that, it is certainly true if you accept item (1) in the theorem.

However, I am still confused because they say that item (1) will be proven in Theorem 5.6. [image: Theorem 5.6].

In Theorem 5.6 they then refer back to equation 5.4, so it appears to me as if there is circular logic. What am I missing?

Comment: I think simply item (1) is used here, so that we already know that $\lambda$ is real.

Answer (score 1):

In (2), you want to prove that a subset of the spectrum (namely the residual spectrum) is empty, so it suffices to consider $\lambda$ in the spectrum, which is a subset of the reals. Of course then $\lambda=\bar \lambda$.

In any case, the identity $\operatorname{ran}(A-\lambda)^\perp=\ker(A-\lambda)$ also holds for $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$ simply because the spaces on both sides are $\{0\}$ for every element not in the spectrum of $A$.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. That did occur to me, but what is confusing me is that they don't prove the fact that the spectrum is a subset of the reals; they delay that until the next theorem (theorem 5.6), and they rely on equation (5.4) in theorem 5.6.

Comment: They cannot use (5.4) in the form stated here, but $\operatorname{ran}(A-\lambda)^\perp=\ker(A-\bar \lambda)$ still implies that $\operatorname{ran}(A-\lambda)$ is dense as $\ker(A-\bar\lambda)=\{0\}$ by the same argument as for $\ker(A-\lambda)$.